# Django DB connections validation at runserver

Tags: python, django

In our project we are not going by the Django ORM so i cant use Django db validations. I have a requirement of validating DB connection before starting the server. Can anybody help me with the best practice to achieve the same ??

What I have in my mind is introducing few lines of code or module in manage.py that would validate the DB connectivity before going to  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) . Is my approach correct or is there a better way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own manage command which will check db connection and if it's ok call *runserver* command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.db import connection


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select 1")
        call_command('runserver')
```

Comment: which is the most apt place to keep this command file ? i dont want to keep it in django\core\management\commands rather i want to locate it in our project dir @Eugene

Comment: manage commands should be placed in app/management/commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: In production, you shouldn't be using runserver. Maybe the app's wsgi.py is the best place to put the check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the runserver command and inject your test before running it:

project/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'project.app',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    ]
```

The order is important because it dictates which app will overload the other's management commands.

project/app/management/commands/runserver.py

```
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            #test your connections
        except SomeException as e:
            #handle your error
        super(BaseCommand, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way your runserver command always checks your constraint before each run.  You can also reraise the error in the except clause if you want the command *not* to run.  This resulted in the init code being run twice, I'm not sure why.

If you are using django-devserver then the import becomes:

```
from django_devserver.devserver.management.commands.runserver import Command as BaseCommand
```